# Match sum of values to value totals by group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to check whether the sum of `lines` in C column is equal to the `Total` value in B column for each `Num` individually:

```
Num      Total    lines 
 1        200      100
 1        200      100
 2        150       50
 2        150       50
 2        150       50
 3        400      200
 3        400      100
 3        400       50
 3        400       25
 3        400       25
```

Any ideas? (In the example they all do equate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want may be something like:

> =SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)=B2

applied to the top non-header row and copied down to suit.

This, for each `Num`, sums the `lines` total and compares it to the `Total` for the corresponding `Num`. Result for your example is TRUE in every case.

Answer (score 0):

An entirely different approach would be to use a PivotTable and merely compare visually (or by formula) the Row Labels and Grand Total rows:

[image: SO18247710 example]

Where there is a mismatch it can be located by drilling down.